# Constant size commitment to a bivariate polynomial

Tags: commitments

---

In [this](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477178/6477178.pdf) paper by Kate et al, a constant size polynomial commitment scheme is described.

The commitment scheme assumes a public reference string:

\begin{align*}
\Big\{
\{ g^{ \tau^i }, g^{ \alpha \tau^i }  \}_{i=-d}^{d} \}, \ \ 
\{ h^{ \tau^i }, h^{ \alpha \tau^i }  \}_{i=-d}^{d}, \ \ e(g, h^{\alpha} ) 
\Big\}
\end{align*}

where $\alpha, \tau \in \mathbb{F}$ are two secret values and $d$ is a large integer. The commitment goes as follows:

- Commit: let $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ with degree at most $d$. The commitment is a group element $F$ defined by
  \begin{align*}
  F := g^{\alpha f(\tau) }. 
  \end{align*}
- To open the commitment to a certain value $z$, compute the proof $W$ which is another field element, defined by:
  \begin{align*}
  W := g^{ \frac{ f(\tau) -f(z) }{ \tau-z } }
  \end{align*}
- To verify a correct opening given $(F, z, (v, W) )$:
  \begin{align*}
  e(W,  h^{\alpha \tau}  )  \cdot  e(g^v \cdot W^{-z}, h^{\alpha} )  == e(F, h^{\alpha } )
  \end{align*}

We note that the the commitment to the polynomial $f$ is constant size, as well as the proof of correct opening for a given value $z$.

My question is,

> Given the above reference string, or a similar reference string of roughly the same size (linear in $d$), is there a known constant size commitment scheme to a **bivariate** polynomial?

Comment: Notation is completely different, comparing to the paper referenced: there is no $\tau$, and $\alpha$ is used for powers of exponents. Symmetric pairing is supposed in the paper: both inputs are from the same group. Variable $v$ is undefined in the main verification equation, that should be $f(z)$. An extra $\alpha$ was introduced somehow, so that completeness does not hold for this verification equation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue for the bivariate polynomials is the coefficients of the polynomial $f(x,y)$. Since $\tau$ is a secret value then to calculate $g^{\alpha f(\tau)}$ we can use the public parameters. As you know, the users can obtain the coefficients based on a standard basis and then solve a multiplication.
$$g^{\alpha f(\tau)}=\prod_{i=0}^{n}{(g^{ \alpha \tau^i })}^{f_i}$$
For a univariate polynomial, the coefficients of $f_i$ are constant while if we consider bivariate polynomials then it is necessary to evaluate a second polynomial on the $\tau$. Precisely, the standard basis $(1,X,X^2,...,X^d)$ forms the univariate polynomials and the coefficients for a bivariate polynomial are changing by the second variable.